# Task.WhenAll finishing before Tasks have completed

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

My code is continuing to execute before all tasks have been completed.

I've had a look at other people with a similar problem but can't see anything obvious!

```
static Task MoveAccountAsync(MoverParams moverParams)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Moving {0}", moverParams.Account.Name);
            moverParams.Account.Mover.RefreshRoom();
            moverParams.Account.Mover.PathfindTo(moverParams.Room);
        });

    }

static async void MoveAccountsAsync(List<Account> accounts, int room)
    {

        List<Task> theTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (Account account in accounts)
        {
            // Create a new task and add it to the task list
            theTasks.Add(MoveAccountAsync(new MoverParams(account, room)));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(theTasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished moving.");
    }
```

Then simply calling it from static main:

```
MoveAccountsAsync(theAccounts, room);
```

Help much appreciated!

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: You cannot await an `async void` method. It is fire-and-forget. Always use `async Task` instead, except for event handlers. From within `Main()` use `.Wait()` on the resulting `Task`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async void` methods are highly discouraged and often times (e.g. here) sign of an issue.

Because you're not awaiting your method call (and you can't `await` it because it returns `void`) caller will not wait for all the work to finish before moving on to the next statement.

Change your method to return `Task` and `await` it to fix the problem. If you're calling into `MoveAccountsAsync` from synchronous context (e.g. `Main` method) use `Wait` to wait on the results. But be aware that in certain conditions (e.g. if run as part of ASP.NET application) that might cause deadlocks.

Comment: So I have to create another task which spawns the child tasks? Then wait on the main task to complete instead of waiting for the child tasks? Apologies this is my first time working with threads!

Comment: `Task` != Thread. Having a task you're waiting on doesn't mean there is a new thread there. Just that there is some work that's happening and you're waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Oops! So is what I said correct? I tried: `Task.Run(() => MoveAccountsAsync(theAccounts, room)).Wait();` when calling, but with the same results as before...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help.